# How to run commands synchronously in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm am making a DVD ripping script and need to run commands synchronously for my script to work properly. I have been trying to using subprocess with no success.  This test code should run for at least 7 seconds.

```
import subprocess
import time

start_time = time.time()

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['timeout', "2"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

p2 = subprocess.Popen(['timeout', "5"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

print(f"Finshed in {time.time() - start_time} Seconds")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Popen.wait` method, which waits for the subprocess to terminate:

```
import subprocess
import time

start_time = time.time()

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', "2"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
p1.wait()

p2 = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', "5"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
p2.wait()

print(f"Finshed in {time.time() - start_time} Seconds")
```

If I run this:

```
(py39) Juans-MacBook-Pro:~ juan$ python -B stackoverflow.py
Finshed in 7.015462160110474 Seconds
```

Note, the `subprocess` docs recommend you use the [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) helper function, which happens to automatically block until the subprocess terminates. It returns a [`subprocess.CompletedProcess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess) object. So:

```
import subprocess
import time

start_time = time.time()

result1 = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', "2"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

result2 = subprocess.run(['sleep', "5"], shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

print(f"Finshed in {time.time() - start_time} Seconds")
```

would be another approach.

Comment: I used it on HandbrakeCLI and it worked great! Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.run()` [1]

```
import subprocess
import time

start_time = time.time()
p1 = subprocess.run(['sleep', "2"])
p2 = subprocess.run(['sleep', "5"])
print(f"Finshed in {time.time() - start_time} Seconds")
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run